# C# Passing functions with parameters as delegates, possible?

Tags: c#, delegates

I have a System.Windows.Form.Timer()

```
myTimer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
myTimer.Interval = 100;
myTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(TimerElapsed);
```

I want to be able the change the function that runs in the timer callback on the fly.
Basically, I'm trying to poll a variable with a timeout, but I want that method for checking that variable to be able to change.
For example:

```
public delegate bool MyFunction(string[] buffer, string str);
static MyFunction timerFunction;
static bool pollVariable

private void TimerElapsed(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timerCount++;

            pollVariable = timerFunction();                 //This doesn't work
            //pollVariable = timerFunction(myBuffer, str);  //This does, but only when I don't pass 
                                                            //any parameters in the Poll function below
        }

private static void PollVaribaleWithTimeout(MyFunction f, int timeout) 
        {
            timerFunction = f;                              //Here is where I want to swap out the 
                                                            // functionality of the timer callback

            timerCount = 0;
            myTimer.Start();
            while(myTimer.enabled)
            {
                    if ((timerCount >= timeout) || (pollVariable = true))
                    {
                        myTimer.Stop();
                    }
            }
        }
```

So at this stage I want to be able to define any number of functions that search a buffer for a certain string via some arbitrary means. So lets make searchFunc1 and searchFunc2.

```
private bool searchFunc1(string[] buffer, string str)
{
        //do stuff
        return true; 
}
private bool searchFunc2(string[] buffer, string str)
{
        //do stuff
        return false;    
}
```

Then somewhere else I'd like to call the poll variable function passing through the specific search function with specific parameters specifying the buffers, strings and timeouts etc.

```
PollVariableWithTimeout(searchFunc1(thisBuffer, "abc"), 200);  //doesn't work
PollVariableWithTimeout(searchFunc2(thatBuffer, "123"), 500);  //doesn't work
//PollVariableWithTimeout(searchFunc1, 300);                   //This does work but doesn't provide me the 
                                                               // functionality of being able to adjust the 
                                                               // parameters at this level
```

Is this possible? Or am I barking up the wrong tree by expecting to call a function with parameters that includes a function with parameters?!
Is there a better way to approach this.
I'm reasonably new to C# coming from a background in C so some stuff regarding delegates is a bit confusing.

Cheers for any help!
Colm

Comment: I think you have a typo at `if ((timerCount >= timeout) || (pollVariable = true))` Should be `==`? Or just `if ((timerCount >= timeout) || pollVariable)`

Comment: Lock and Switch?

Comment: you may use new delegate/Func<bool> `() => searchFunc2(thatBuffer, "123")` 
with `PollVaribaleWithTimeout(Func<bool> f, int timeout)`
or pass `searchFunc2` and parameters as different `PollVaribaleWithTimeout` parameters:
`PollVaribaleWithTimeout(Func<string[], string, bool> f, string[] buffer, string str, int timeout)`